# Unable to launch ejabberd in browser

Tags: elixir, ejabberd

I installed elixir with ejabberd following the instructions in the link:
https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/extending-ejabberd/elixir/

1. Installed elixir on Linux machine.
2. Added ejabberd dependency to its mix.exs
3. Then edited the config.exs, ejabberd.yml files

Started the elixir app.
It started properly.

The following messages were printed on the console:

1. Loading modules for localhost
2. Ejabberd started at node nonode@nohost.
3. cowboy started at http://localhost:4000.

I registered one user at ejabberd server.
It was successfully registered.

But when I enter the url http://localhost:5280/admin in the browser,
It is giving the error page not found.
It is expected to show me the ejabberd server page with nodes, virtual hosts, users info.

Comment: Id `web_admin: true` set in the configuration file?

Comment: which configuration file? ejabberd.yml? web_admin is already true in ejabberd.yml.